# C++ Priority Queue with Struct

Tags: c++, struct, priority-queue

I'm using Priority Queue with Struct

my struct is Node below :

```
struct Node{
int level;
int bound;
int total;};
```

And my priority queue is below :

```
    std::priority_queue<Node> pq;
```

What I want to do is to sort my priority queue(pq) as the value of **Node.bound** so that the Node object whose value of bound is the maximum is at the top of priority queue.

What I found that I have to overload the method 'operator'

So I did it as below

```
bool operator<(Node const& lhs, Node const& rhs) {
return lhs.bound < rhs.bound;}
```

After I overload that method, pq sorted node objects but there are some  often exceptions that 271,268,267,261,**268**,249,**255**,260,**246,256** that 271 is the top value of pq.

What should I do to solve this situation?
I think if I solve this, I could solve my problem perfectly!

Comment: I think the method 'operator' should cover more than two Node objects, isn't it?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] that illustrates the issue?

Comment: @LKM No, the operator is fine. Please post a [mcve]. Currently, you are not showing us the code with the error.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's long c++ algorithm program. I don't know how to create my question as you guys say

Comment: The 'bound' value is the standard. If the bound value is larger, the node struct object having that bound value is high priority

Answer (score 1):

The priority queue keeps the top element (the one it is about to pop) as the first element. The other elements are in an unspecified order.

I am betting the default implementation is to use a heap structure underneath the covers to make it as efficient as possible. Which is why the elements seem to be in a random order.

Note this is why `std::priority_queue` interface only allows you to `pop()` elements and does not provide random access to the elements in the queue.

**Additional note**: The order of the priority queue is defined by the third template parameter. If you do not define this it defaults to `std::less` which by default will use `operator<` to do the comparison.